# Is possible to create animation effects with JSF Pure?

Tags: jsf-2

I wonder if you can create screen effects (such as how to display the button, customize a modal or to flash background colors of a datatable for example) to my page created in JSF Pure (ie, without using Primefaces, RichFaces, and the like). If so, please indicate me sites and / or tutorials where I can check this job, because I researched on google and have not had success.

Grateful for the attention!

Comment: It's the same a asking: How can I do that in plain HTML... Well, use Prime-UI, or any other comparable client-side javascript widget set. But questions like this doe not belong on StackOverflow since they tend to gather opinionated answers (like this one ;-)

Comment: Ok, Thank's Kukeltje

Comment: All due respect, this rhetorical question makes no sense. If it was not possible in pure JSF, then reusable component libraries such as PrimeFaces, RichFaces, and the like would never have been be able to do that. I suggest to take a step back and learn some basic web development concepts first. Among others the often overlooked fact that JSF is in client side context "just" a HTML code generator and all you basically need is a bit of HTML/CSS/JS knowledge so you can simply make sure that you write JSF code in such way that it generates exactly the desired HTML/CSS/JS output.

Comment: BalusC unfortunately my client has restricted the use of PrimeFaces, RichFaces, among others. And I still demanded a beautiful design, so I'm at a dead end, having to appeal to the JavaScript effects.

Comment: I wasn't saying that you must use PF or RF. I just said that your question doesn't make sense. The answer is an obvious "Yes!". Because, if it were "No!", then PF and RF could impossibly have existed.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by friend Kukeltje, I will apply the JavaScript / JQuery in my project.

Thank you!!!